# Is it possible to use SignalR to forward data from another server to your clients?

Tags: .net-core, signalr

My previous experience with SignalR was only as a server, getting data from a database and then updating the webpages accordingly.

I was wondering if it is possible to use SignalR to connect to other servers that shares data via Websockets and then consolidating the data to send out to your own clients, also using SignalR? So something like a forwarder of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .net signalR client to hook nearly anything to the server.  There can be difficulties with waking the server up, so it is important to check the behavior.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio